# Home page at /home-page-name instead of /

Tags: seo, google, redirects

I was wondering if having your home page at

```
http://domain.com/home-page-name
```

instead of just:

```
http://domain.com/
```

would affect SEO?  Not only that, but if users go to `domain.com` they are redirected to `domain.com/home-page-name` within the PHP application.

So I just was wondering if any of that hindered or greatly hindered SEO (namely, Google ranking)?  And if so, why?

Comment: That's fine. No seo issues with this.

Comment: Thank you @JohnConde for such a quick response!  Mind posting that as an answer (as simple as it is lol)?

Comment: Fair enough. Done with some elaboration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no SEO issues with this. When you think about it there is no standard home page URL. No only do different web servers have different default (index.html, default.html, etc) but it's not uncommon for home pages to be in subdirectories (example.com/site/something/home).

Search engines are not going to have any difficulty recognizing it as your homepage as not only will your redirect be a good clue to them, but the linking pattern within your site will also be a good indicator of which page is your "main" page.

Comment: Excellent answer.  Thanks for the thorough explanation! :)

Comment: Further to this answer, providing your homepage does not resolve at `/` as well as `/home` (for example). If your homepage resolves at multiple URL versions then this becomes an issue in terms of SEO.

Comment: Thanks @zigojacko that's really important information to know. Much appreciated. Would hate to have my website suddenly be cut off in search results due to not following protocol